# Boundedness of a closed operator

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

Can I get any help with this problem:

> Let $X, Y$ be Banach spaces, let $D$ be a subspace of $X$, and let
>   $A \colon D \to Y$ be a closed linear operator. If $D$ is a closed subspace of $X$,
>   prove that $A$ is bounded.

thank you.

Comment: Have you heard of the closed graph theorem?

Comment: yeah, I was thinking about "A closed subspace of a Banach space is a Banach space" and use the closed graph theorem. but it sounded too easy, did I miss anything? thanx.

Comment: You missed that it really is that easy, apparently.

Comment: so, just that.... huh, thank you sir!